# Remove method to filter letters in customizable String keeps returning a multiplied string rather than result

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, oop, character

I have a homework assignment in which I have to create a remove, reverse, and filterLetters method for a CustomString class. The methods are supposed to do as the name says, in the argument of the remove method, you provide a string with letters that you want removed from the actual 'myString' you have and the method is supposed to filter through a character array of your string and argument and see if it matches with the string.

If the characters match, then the method is supposed to remove it by not adding it to a new string, while if they don't match, the character should get added into the new string being built and returned. The other two methods work the exact same and are provided with strings in the arguments to reverse capatilization or filter letters in.

I keep getting the same problem in all of my methods, the nested for-loop I created for my character arrays runs through the character array for the argument string, and for each character in that array, it runs through the current string characters to see if the characters in the argument and current string match to remove, reverse, or filter. However, that also means that the current string is being run through multiple times, and being added multiple times if it doesn't match, so instead of the string I need, I get a multiplied version of that string.

I have tried using the continue; operator but then I get a shortened version, what I need is that once those characters have been added, even if the for-loop runs again to check them, it doesn't add. However, I don't know how to check for that since there can be repetitive letters in the strings so you can't cross check to see if they've already been added into the new string being built.

My code is below, I've only added the remove method code since I have the same problem throughout and I appreciate all the help in advance!

```
public CustomString() {
        // TODO Implement constructor
        this.myString = null; 
        this.isSet = false;
```

This javadoc should explain what the method is supposed to work like.

```
/**
     * Returns a new string version of the current string where the alphabetical characters specified in the given arg, are removed.
     *   
     * The alphabetical characters to be removed are case insensitive.  
     * All non-alphabetical characters are unaffected.
     * If the current string is null, empty, or has not been set to a value, this method should return an empty string.
     *
     * Example(s):
     * - For a current string "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19.", calling remove("ra6") would return "my lucky numbes e 6, 8, nd 19."
     * - For a current string "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19.", calling remove("6,.") would return "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19."
     * - For a current string "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19.", calling remove("") would return "my lucky numbers are 6, 8, and 19."
     * 
     * Remember: This method builds and returns a new string, and does not directly modify the myString field.
     * 
     * @param arg the string containing the alphabetical characters to be removed from the current string
     * @return new string in which the alphabetical characters specified in the arg are removed
     */
    public String remove(String arg) {
        // TODO Implement method
        String newString; 
        char[] myStrArr = myString.toCharArray(); 
        char[] argArr = arg.toCharArray(); 
        String newStr = "";  //a,1 and za,,231
        for (int i = 0; i < argArr.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < myStrArr.length; x++) {
                if(Character.isLetter(argArr[i]) && Character.isLetter(myStrArr[x])) {
                    if ((Character.toUpperCase(argArr[i]) == myStrArr[x]) || (Character.toLowerCase(argArr[i]) == myStrArr[x])) {
                        continue; 
                    } else {
                        String newChar = Character.toString(myStrArr[x]);
                        newStr += newChar;

                    }
                } else if (Character.isDigit(argArr[i]) && Character.isDigit(myStrArr[x])) {
                    if(argArr[i] == myStrArr[x]) {
                        continue; 
                    } else {
                        String newChar = Character.toString(myStrArr[x]);
                        newStr += newChar; 
                    }
                } else { 
                    continue; 
                }
            }
        }
        return newStr;
    }
```

This is the result:

Current String: abc@,123
New String after using remove("a3,"): bc12
What we should get after removing: bc@,12

Comment: *`All non-alphabetical characters are unaffected.`* For `abc@,123` New String after using `remove("a3,")` what we should get after removing: `bc@,12`.  Why are you removing the `3` since it is not alphabetic.  Seems like the only thing you should remove is the `a` resulting in `bc@,123`.

Comment: Regarding your _JavaDoc_ specification, _"... All non-alphabetical characters are unaffected. ..."_, does this not conflict with producing _bc@,12_ over _bc@,123_?  Only the _a_ would be affected by _'a3,'_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest problem is too much code - it's very hard to read and more complicated than it needs to be. There are built-in methods for this task. Given

```
String toRemove;
String str;
```

The code to make the replacement is just:

```
return str == null || str.isEmpty() ? "" : str.replaceAll("(?i)[" + toRemove.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "") + "]", "");
```

The `(?i)` flag makes the match case insensitive.

`toRemove.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z]", "")` deletes all non-alphanumerics from the characters to remove.

Comment: You've skipped a step, the _JavaDoc_ for _remove_ has requirements.  _"... [1] The alphabetical characters to be removed are case insensitive. [2] All non-alphabetical characters are unaffected. [3] If the current string is null, empty, or has not been set to a value, this method should return an empty string. ..."_.

Comment: @Reilas missed case insensitive. fixed now. note that point 2 is covered as only characters expressly in `toRemove` are affected.

Comment: @WJS Thx. nice pickup, which I've taken care of too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not make `myStrArr` be the outer loop and then for the inner loop with `argArr`, use `break` to stop it (rather than using `continue`), because you've finished dealing with the `myStrArr` letter and so can move on to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a nested for loop in this case. There is a simpler way and far more readable.

You can loop through the `args` character array and add each letter character to a set. Once the set is created, loop through `myString` looking for matches in the set. If the character matches a character in the set, do nothing, otherwise append it to a `StringBuilder`. We can avoid creating a bunch of temporary `String` objects too, so we use `StringBuilder` instead of concatenating strings inside the loop.

Notice I added a lowercase and uppercase version of each character found in `arg`. This will make the check case-insenstive.

```java
public String remove(String arg) {
    if (myString == null || !isSet) {
        return "";
    }
    
    // Create a set of characters to remove
    Set<Character> toRemove = new HashSet<>();
    for (char c : arg.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
            toRemove.add(Character.toLowerCase(c)); // add lowercase of the character
            toRemove.add(Character.toUpperCase(c)); // add uppercase of the character
        }
    }
    
    // concatenating strings inside a loop is a bad idea 
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder(); // use StringBuilder for better performance
    for (char c : myString.toCharArray()) {
        // Only remove it if it exists in the set
        if (!toRemove.contains(c)) {
            newStr.append(c);
        }
    }
    
    return newStr.toString();
}
```

Additionally, I am not sure if you have control over the instance variables or constructor, but there is really no need to track `isSet` or set `myString` to null. I would just create a constructor like below:

```java
public class CustomString {

    private String myString;

    public CustomString(String initialString) {
        this.myString = initialString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Another way would be to only add the lowercase version of the _char_ to _toRemove_, and then utilize the _[Character#toLowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase(char))_ method with _toRemove#contains_.  _if (!toRemove.contains(Character.toLowerCase(c)))_.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you have many problems in your code (mostly due to it's incomplete). But the following will fulfill the requirements of the remove method. It is presumed that `myString` and `isSet` are visible to the method.

- check special conditions
- allocate a StringBuilder object.
- convert argument string to lowercase
- iterate thru the character.
- if the index of the charsToRemove does not contain the char (i.e index == -1) then append it to StringBuilder
- when the loop finishes, return the StringBuilder as a string.

**Note:** it is important to preserve the original case when appending to the StringBuilder.

```
String myString = "AbC@,123EfGh";

public String remove(String charsToRemove) {
    if(myString == null || myString.isEmpty() || !isSet) {
           return "";
    }
      
    charsToRemove = charsToRemove.toLowerCase();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       
    for (char ch : myString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(ch) || 
             charsToRemove.indexOf(Character.toLowerCase(ch)) == -1) {
                 sb.append(ch); 
        }
     }
     return sb.toString();
}

myString = remove("a3,Eh");
System.out.println(myString);
```

prints

```
bC@,123fG
```

Comment: As a note, their _JavaDoc_ for _remove_ says, _"... non-alphabetical characters are unaffected ..."_.

Comment: @Reilas Yes, I agree which is why I ignore non-letters when replacing.  And I made a similar comment to the OP before you did.   Did I miss something because I don't understand why you made the comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *regex pattern* to remove the matching characters.

Here is a pattern, where *<arg>* represents the value of *arg*.

```
(?i)[\Q<arg>\E&&a-z]+
```

This should cover the first 2 conditions,

> - *The alphabetical characters to be removed are case insensitive.*
> - *All non-alphabetical characters are unaffected.*
> - *If the current string is null, empty, or has not been set to a value, > this method should return an empty string.*

Additionally, you'll want to check for an empty *arg* value, as this will invalidate the pattern.

This will match the examples given in the method's *JavaDoc*.

```java
public String remove(String arg) {
    if (myString == null || myString.isEmpty()) return "";
    if (arg.isEmpty()) return myString;
    return myString.replaceAll("(?i)[" + Pattern.quote(arg) + "&&a-z]+", "");
}
```